# Query ViewData, then change value based on result

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this code snippet in my controller

```
outputmodel4.Add(new SP_data.student()
                {
                    student_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["student_id"],
                    student_no = (string)SPOutput4["student_no"],
                    course_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["course_id"],
                    floor_no = (int)SPOutput4["floor_no"],
                    tutor_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["tutor_id"],
                    capacity_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["capacity_id"],
                });

            }
            ViewData["Output"] = outputmodel4;
```

what I am trying to do it query Capacity_id, and if the number is (say) 2, then display "All Most Full" on my view.

I think the say to accomplish this is

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Output"] as IEnumerable<app.Models.SP_data.student>)
  {
  <TD>
  @if (item.capacity_id = 2)
   {
     All Most Full
   }
   else if (item.capacity_id = 5)
   {
     Full
   }
    else if    etc..
  </TD>
}
```

.. but I getting errors in the view

> Cannot implicitly convert type decimal to bool

can someone please advise, and help ?

thanks

Comment: Use `==` for comparisons, not `=`.

Comment: Create a view model that is tailored to your view  You view model doesn't need a capacity_id field, it needs a CapacityMessage.  This moved your business logic out of the view and into the controller action (at a minimum) and makes it testable.

Comment: hi, If it use                 @if (item.status_id == 2)
                {
                    @Html.Display("full")
                  } , nothing gets displayed

Comment: my fault, should use <text</text> instead of html.Display